# Perl Strings as function references

Tags: string, perl, function

I'm not sure if the title is exactly right.  What I'm trying to do is this (I've already gotten the database handle from DBI):

```
my $idcenter = 4;
my $getCenter = $dbh->prepare(
<<SQLEND
select * from center
where uidcenter = ?
SQLEND
);

my @tables = ("Center");
foreach $table (@tables) {
    my $func = "get$table";
    $func->bind_param(1, $idcenter);
    etc.
}
```

So, how do I construct a variable that points (? is that right?) to a function?  Is there a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a hash

```
my %get_table = (
    center => $getCenter,
);

$get_table{"center"}->bind_param(1, $idcenter);
```

Comment: Oh, thank you!  I was using a hash table before, but I didn't put the dollar sign in front of getCenter.

Comment: Make sure you have [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) at the top of each and every perl script.  If you did and you forgot that dollar sign, perl would give you the following helpful error: `Bareword "getCenter" not allowed while "strict subs" in use`